# Facebook Graph API Real-Time Updates when liking a post. Is it possible?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Using the Graph API to receive updates in real-time, is it possible to be notified when someone likes a post made by another user?

Comment: did you check out the facebook docs?

Comment: Of course. It mentions getting notifications for User & Page objects. There is no specific mentions of likes of posts. It does list feed, but I'm not sure if that includes someone else liking a post on that feed. At the moment it's not convenient to setup a URL reachable by facebook to receive the notifications. I was hoping someone could tell me.